# How can I give widgets thickness in the z direction?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I implemented an effect that I found on this medium article https://medium.com/flutter/perspective-on-flutter-6f832f4d912e
that allows you rotate widgets in 3d space. My only problem with this is that all of my widgets seem to have no thickness in the z direction so unsightly things like this happen:

[image: App screenshot]

My unrotated logo looks like this:

[image: Original Logo]

And this is the code I used to create this rotation effect:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PerspectiveContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  PerspectiveContainer({Key key, @required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PerspectiveState createState() => _PerspectiveState();
}

class _PerspectiveState extends State<PerspectiveContainer> {
  Offset _offset = Offset.zero;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform(
      transform: Matrix4.identity()
        ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001) // perspective
        ..rotateX(0.004 * _offset.dy)
        ..rotateY(-0.004 * _offset.dx),
      alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onPanUpdate: (details) => setState(() => _offset += details.delta),
        onDoubleTap: () => setState(() => _offset = Offset.zero),
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So would it be possible to give my BINGO widget thickness in the z direction?(The bingo logo was made with a Table widget)

Comment: I think you can't. It is after all a projection of a 2D plane. So there are no 3D models or whatsoever behind it

Comment: Flutter does not have 3D support as yet. A workaround might be rendering the same thing with a little offset and darker colours.

Comment: There is no z-axis on a 2D plane. A hack we use in css to get 3d effects was shifting a copy of the top and left/right offset which makes it appear 3D but it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Material Design works sometimes with shadows and elevation here, which would give you some 3D look, although it is actually 2d. https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html#elevation-in-material-design

Some Widgets in Flutter have an `elevation` attribute, e.g. `Card`.